ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
import telebot

token = "мой токен"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
@bot.message_handler(commands =['start'])

def start_message(message):
    stMes ="""
Привет!  

Я ваш помощник в ведении финансов!   
С помощью меня вы сможете:

- Удобно записывать свои доходы и расходы
- Получать отчеты о своих финансах
- Устанавливать финансовые цели
- Напоминания о платежах

Давайте начнем! Для начала введите команду /help, чтобы узнать, как я могу помочь вам.
"""
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,stMes)


try:# метод для обработки новых сообщений пользователя
    bot.infinity_polling()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Бот остановлен.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Произошла ошибка: {e}")

Всем доброго дня, только начинаю писать код. Пишу бота на питоне. При запуске кода в консоль выводится следующее

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"D:_kringe\Шмурдяк\lalala\аааааааа.venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot_init_.py",
line 1101, in infinity_polling
self.polling(non_stop=True, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,   File
"D:_kringe\Шмурдяк\lalala\аааааааа.venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot_init_.py",
line 1186, in polling
logger.info('Starting your bot with username: [@%s]', self.user.username)
^^^^^^^^^

Токен верный, подключение к интернету стабильное, очень нуждаюсь в вашей помощи

спасибо, проблема была с антивирусом, который блокировал подключение, как я поняла
